# Columns 1-4 and 8 gets result but 5-7 don't - in onchange dropdown menu from database

Tags: php, sql, onchange, dropdown

I was able to get results from the dropdown menu and from database. However, Q2, Q2, Q3 does not show result but the last column (Final) gets result. Did I do something wrong?

Gladly, I was able to apply the onchange event. Everything is okay but not the columns 5-7. I will gladly appreciate your help.

```
        <?php



    $selected='';

    function get_options($select)
    {
        $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'jared17', 'hbadb') 
        or die ('Cannot connect to db');

        $result = $conn->query("select * from students");

        $options='';
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            $LRN = $row['LRN'];
             $Last = $row['Last_Name']; 
            $First = $row['First_Name'];
            if($LRN == $_POST['Students'])
            {
                $options.='<option value="'.$LRN.'" selected>'.$Last.', '.$First.'</option>';

            }
            else
            {
                $options.='<option value="'.$LRN.'">'.$Last.', '.$First.'</option>';
            }
        }
        return $options;
    }
        if (isset($_POST['Students'])) {
            $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'jared17', 'hbadb') 
        or die ('Cannot connect to db');

        $result = $conn->query("select * from students");
        $lrn = $_POST['Students'];
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Last_Name, First_Name, Level, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, FINAL FROM english WHERE LRN = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $lrn);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($last, $first, $level, $q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $final);
        $stmt->fetch();
        echo "<table><tr><th>LRN</th><th>Name</th><th>Level</th><th>Q1</th><th>Q2</th><th>Q3</th><th>Q4</th><th>Final</th></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>$lrn</td><td>$last, $first</td><td>$level</td><td>$q1</td><td>$q2</td><td>$q3</td><td>$q4</td><td>$final</td></tr></table>";
    }




    echo "<html>";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "<form method=POST>";
    echo "<select name=Students onchange=this.form.submit();>";

        echo get_options();



    echo "</select>";

    echo "</form>";

    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";
    ?>
```

Comment: The code looks correct so it should be the data. Are you sure that your query is returning values for the missing fields ?